# How would I irregularly space x-axis data in highcharts that ISN'T represented in a datetime format?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have data that is returned in an integer format that is based on time, but isn't a measurement of time that we normally use.

The integers are not evenly spaced, so I'm trying reflect that in the chart.

Is there any way to do this **without** the time in milliseconds?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: xCategories(),
        title: {
          text: 'Time'
        },
        ordinal: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: getInterestRates()
    }]
});
```

`ordinal: true` doesn't seem to work because this isn't a formal time format.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Example Data:**

```
 {
     "integerOfTime": 1024,
     "thingMeasuredOverTime": 0,
 },
 {
     "integerOfTime": 2048,
     "thingMeasuredOverTime": 5,
  },
  {
      "integerOfTime": 4096,
      "thingMeasuredOverTime": 5,
  },
```

Comment: Are you using Highstock? Also, do you have an example of your data? Is it like `[[5,10],[17,9],[44,14]...]`?

Comment: No I'm using HighChart, not stock.. Will edit with an example of data.

Comment: You can also use a [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) and create a function which will position ticks as you need.

Comment: Yup, just use the numbers as your x values, but don't use a datetime axis type (or categories). What you're describing is how it works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a x-axis of type `linear` (this is the default type), and passing an array of `[x,y]` pairs as `data` of your series. Given your example data format you'll have to convert it into this format.

A simple Highcharts example would be ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebeshq3v/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'linear'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [[1024,0],[2048,5],[4096,5]]
    }]
});
```

The format conversion could be done like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yu1zb9b/)):

```
var json = [{
    "integerOfTime": 1024,
     "thingMeasuredOverTime": 0,
}, {
     "integerOfTime": 2048,
     "thingMeasuredOverTime": 5,
}, {
      "integerOfTime": 4096,
      "thingMeasuredOverTime": 5,
}];

var data = [];

$.each(json, function(i, v) {
    data.push([v.integerOfTime, v.thingMeasuredOverTime]);
});
```

Comment: The challenge I'm running in to labels. When I do that, there is no way to have a custom label (a more readable date).

Comment: Well what does "1024" represent? Just use a label formatter to change it into whatever you want.

Comment: It represents a block of time. The labels are also in the API, so it says things like "17 hours" or "212 days". I'm not sure how to access the data from the API again within the formatter loop.. But that is a different question. 

I think the above adequately answers the original ask.